# Store auto.arima summary in multiple vectors

Tags: r, list, vector

I performed auto.arima function on multiple ts variables in a list

```
arima_train <- lapply(train_data, function(x) auto.arima(x$Value))
```

I can get the summaries of the function for all the variables

```
> for (i in (1:16)) summary(arima_train[[i]])
Series: x$Value 
ARIMA(0,1,0)                    

sigma^2 estimated as 2.808:  log likelihood=-137.4
AIC=276.81   AICc=276.86   BIC=279.07

Training set error measures:
                    ME     RMSE      MAE        MPE     MAPE      MASE      ACF1
Training set 0.0451375 1.664175 1.228471 0.04069765 2.268046 0.9866678 -0.188887
Series: x$Value 
ARIMA(0,0,0) with non-zero mean 

Coefficients:
      intercept
      5251.6806
s.e.   187.3747

sigma^2 estimated as 2563468:  log likelihood=-632.91
AIC=1269.81   AICc=1269.99   BIC=1274.37

Training set error measures:
                        ME     RMSE     MAE       MPE    MAPE      MASE       ACF1
Training set -2.829471e-12 1589.926 1012.06 -6.179073 17.3668 0.8272841 0.06356198
Series: x$Value 
ARIMA(1,1,0) with drift         

Coefficients:
         ar1   drift
      0.4006  0.3324
s.e.  0.1086  0.0907

sigma^2 estimated as 0.2205:  log likelihood=-46.04
AIC=98.08   AICc=98.44   BIC=104.87

Training set error measures:
                       ME      RMSE       MAE          MPE      MAPE     MASE       ACF1
Training set 0.0003775476 0.4597061 0.3308142 0.0007945521 0.1444236 0.669588 0.05640966
Series: x$Value 
ARIMA(0,1,0) with drift         

Coefficients:
        drift
      54.8873
s.e.  14.8586

sigma^2 estimated as 15900:  log likelihood=-443.67
AIC=891.34   AICc=891.51   BIC=895.86

Training set error measures:
                     ME     RMSE      MAE         MPE     MAPE      MASE        ACF1
Training set 0.07422375 124.3296 99.95529 -0.08126397 1.520543 0.9287823 -0.03885156
Series: x$Value 
ARIMA(0,2,1)                    

Coefficients:
          ma1
      -0.9171
s.e.   0.0565

sigma^2 estimated as 100261:  log likelihood=-502.59
AIC=1009.17   AICc=1009.35   BIC=1013.67

Training set error measures:
                   ME     RMSE      MAE        MPE      MAPE      MASE       ACF1
Training set 68.51967 309.9734 221.9339 0.04873783 0.1559967 0.9006235 -0.1312991
Series: x$Value 
ARIMA(1,2,1)                    

Coefficients:
         ar1      ma1
      0.2549  -0.9151
s.e.  0.1297   0.0538

sigma^2 estimated as 0.8075:  log likelihood=-91.49
AIC=188.98   AICc=189.34   BIC=195.72

Training set error measures:
                     ME      RMSE       MAE         MPE      MAPE      MASE        ACF1
Training set -0.1095264 0.8733085 0.6821252 -0.08248981 0.5255063 0.8663844 -0.02072697
Series: x$Value 
ARIMA(2,1,2)                    

Coefficients:
          ar1     ar2     ma1     ma2
      -0.1269  0.4314  0.7658  0.3584
s.e.   0.1816  0.1818  0.1826  0.1581

sigma^2 estimated as 0.04297:  log likelihood=12.48
AIC=-14.95   AICc=-14.03   BIC=-3.64

Training set error measures:
                      ME     RMSE       MAE      MPE     MAPE      MASE        ACF1
Training set 0.006785029 0.199965 0.1498849 1.903016 13.18623 0.6692976 -0.01844039
Series: x$Value 
ARIMA(0,2,2)                    

Coefficients:
          ma1      ma2
      -0.2629  -0.5857
s.e.   0.0920   0.0893

sigma^2 estimated as 1.257:  log likelihood=-106.99
AIC=219.97   AICc=220.33   BIC=226.72

Training set error measures:
                     ME     RMSE       MAE        MPE      MAPE      MASE       ACF1
Training set -0.1654204 1.089599 0.8857888 -0.1206975 0.6571573 0.8396662 0.08537194
Series: x$Value 
ARIMA(0,0,0) with non-zero mean 

Coefficients:
intercept  
     0.25  

sigma^2 estimated as 0:  log likelihood=Inf
AIC=-Inf   AICc=-Inf   BIC=-Inf

Training set error measures:
             ME RMSE MAE MPE MAPE MASE ACF1
Training set  0    0   0   0    0  NaN  NaN
Series: x$Value 
ARIMA(0,1,1)                    

Coefficients:
          ma1
      -0.3715
s.e.   0.1246

sigma^2 estimated as 877.4:  log likelihood=-340.9
AIC=685.8   AICc=685.97   BIC=690.32

Training set error measures:
                   ME     RMSE      MAE         MPE     MAPE      MASE       ACF1
Training set 1.621179 29.20693 21.85996 -0.05931622 5.767894 0.9993928 0.03373764
Series: x$Value 
ARIMA(1,2,1)                    

Coefficients:
         ar1      ma1
      0.2877  -0.9395
s.e.  0.1332   0.0528

sigma^2 estimated as 0.07365:  log likelihood=-7.22
AIC=20.43   AICc=20.82   BIC=27

Training set error measures:
                      ME      RMSE      MAE         MPE     MAPE     MASE        ACF1
Training set -0.02910269 0.2632887 0.193597 -0.02640935 0.181013 0.754128 -0.06465092
Series: x$Value 
ARIMA(0,0,0) with non-zero mean 

Coefficients:
      intercept
         0.3792
s.e.     0.0827

sigma^2 estimated as 0.4989:  log likelihood=-76.62
AIC=157.25   AICc=157.42   BIC=161.8

Training set error measures:
                        ME      RMSE      MAE  MPE MAPE      MASE        ACF1
Training set -3.251722e-14 0.7013751 0.512037 -Inf  Inf 0.7256413 -0.09038341
Series: x$Value 
ARIMA(0,1,0) with drift         

Coefficients:
         drift
      -88.7606
s.e.   28.2956

sigma^2 estimated as 57661:  log likelihood=-489.4
AIC=982.8   AICc=982.98   BIC=987.33

Training set error measures:
                    ME     RMSE      MAE         MPE     MAPE      MASE        ACF1
Training set 0.2040244 236.7675 186.6802 -0.07011135 1.570809 0.9429632 -0.08296941
Series: x$Value 
ARIMA(0,1,1) with drift         

Coefficients:
          ma1   drift
      -0.8659  0.0907
s.e.   0.1172  0.0137

sigma^2 estimated as 0.4673:  log likelihood=-73.42
AIC=152.83   AICc=153.19   BIC=159.62

Training set error measures:
                      ME      RMSE       MAE        MPE     MAPE      MASE      ACF1
Training set -0.04660173 0.6692201 0.4396176 -0.6847646 3.393219 0.9150644 0.1119422
Series: x$Value 
ARIMA(2,1,2) with drift         

Coefficients:
         ar1      ar2      ma1     ma2   drift
      1.3171  -0.8973  -1.2696  0.7378  0.1369
s.e.  0.0973   0.0889   0.1584  0.1495  0.0916

sigma^2 estimated as 0.9726:  log likelihood=-97.5
AIC=207.01   AICc=208.32   BIC=220.58

Training set error measures:
                       ME      RMSE      MAE      MPE     MAPE      MASE        ACF1
Training set -0.007610831 0.9441978 0.627121 23.63108 55.34784 0.9207112 -0.00091189
Series: x$Value 
ARIMA(1,0,0) with non-zero mean 

Coefficients:
         ar1  intercept
      0.3912     0.1423
s.e.  0.1076     0.0368

sigma^2 estimated as 0.03781:  log likelihood=16.67
AIC=-27.34   AICc=-26.99   BIC=-20.51

Training set error measures:
                      ME      RMSE       MAE  MPE MAPE      MASE       ACF1
Training set 0.000930651 0.1917348 0.1362479 -Inf  Inf 0.8794182 0.05445404
```

I want to create multiple vectors which should be able to save the following information for all the 16 variables

1. Order
2. AICc value
3. Log Likelyhood (Fit) etc.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the AIC and Log Likelihood using `arima_train$coef` and `arima_train$aic`. For coefficients, use `coef(arima_train)`. You could get the order by summing the coefficients